# Literature on network-flow (optimization) approximation algorithms

Tags: reference-request, optimization, network-flow

I've been searching on literature on approximation algorithms in the context of network-flow problems (optimization) to finish my bachelor degree.

However, I have been looking in several well-known algorithm books but, I haven't yet found something. Most books don't go beyond Ford-Fulkerson and/or Edmond-Karp in respect to network-flow problems, and the sections explaining approximation algorithms discuss some algorithms not relating to network-flow optimization.

Could someone point me towards appropriate literature? I prefer books instead of papers.

Comment: You might like Schrijver's Combinatorial Optimization, it contains *a lot* of discussion and references to network flow. I just checked, and e.g. its chapter on maximum flow lists around 20 algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

In his [FOCS2013 (Best Paper award) work](https://madry.mit.edu/docs/matching_flow.pdf), Aleksander Mądry gives a $\widetilde O(m^{\frac{10}{7}})$-time for exact max-flow and gives a nice survey on the existing techniques (including near-linear time for $(1+\epsilon)$-approximation in undirected graphs).

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of literature in the computer vision community, as network flow has been used for many purposes.  I know I've read survey papers from computer vision folks that compare a number of different algorithms for network flow to figure out which ones work best for computer vision applications.

For one example application, you could look at "seam carving": https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1435417.1435437